# passing parameters through url to view django

Tags: python, django

I'm having some difficulty passing values to my view through url.

So far, I've managed to run my view without any issues.

view.py (draws a graph):

```
def draw(request)
    ....
    ....
    return HttpResponse (buffer.getvalue(), content_type="Image/png")
```

but I need my view to take input from users, so I edited it and added an extra parameter:

```
def draw(request, loan_amount)
     loanAmount = loan_amount
     .....
```

The user input is passed from a form, to another view:

```
def search_member(request):
     loanAmount = request.GET.get('desired_loan')
     return render(request, 'blog/search_member.html', {'loanAmount':loanAmount)
```

In my template, I insert the user input in the draw's parameter:

```
<img src="http://test.com/graph/{{ loanAmount }}">
```

This is suppose to draw an image base on the user input, instead I get no image at all.

If I remove the parameter, the image works fine. I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with the setup of the parameter, most likely in the template, or url:

```
url(r'^graph/(?P<desired_loan>\d+)/$', views.draw, name='draw'),
```

I have tested the view, form and everything else, they all work. How can I narrow down this problem to find the solution?

Any direction/help would be appreciated,

thanks,

```
<form method="GET" action="/search_member/" class="navbar-form pull-left">

            <input type="number" step = "any" id="searchBox" class="input-medium search-query" name="desired_loan" placeholder="Desired Loan"><br>
            <input type="number" step = "any" id="searchBox" class="input-medium search-query" name="repayment_time" placeholder="Payment Time"><br>

            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Draw Graph" >

        </form><br>
        <img src="http://test.com/graph/{{ loanAmount }}">
```

screen shot:

[image: The picture doesn't show]

Comment: path to image is not correct - look into loading static

Comment: @NabeelAhmed Hi Nabeel, why am I able to load <img src="http://test.com/graph/"> but not <img src="http://test.com/graph/{{ loan_amount }}"> ?? Meanwhile I will read about loading static.

Comment: What is the imgurl you see in your browser

Comment: @Aison http://test.com/graph/10000 (if I input 10000)

Comment: Have you set your STATIC_URL in settings?

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/' ---- STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fo url like

```
url(r'^graph/(?P<desired_loan>\d+)/$', views.draw, name='draw'),
```

Change your view to:

```
def draw(request, *args, **kwargs):
 loanAmount = kwargs['desired_loan']
 .....
```

Then change in template:

```
<img src="{% url 'graph' loanAmount %}">
```

Comment: If you use `{% url 'graph' loanAmount %}` what error will you have? And change `def draw(request, loan_amount)` to `def draw(request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: In your latest update, I get 2016-08-22 12:29:43,515 :Not Found: /static/path/to/user image/10000/img.png. I have made the necessary changes. Can you please change your code to before your update.

Comment: I get the following error, just read the error log: **ymin = (-desiredLoan - (repaymentTime * 25)) TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'**

Comment: `loanAmount = int(kwargs['desired_loan'])`